# Exception: Build process failed

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop, flutter-desktop

When I try running this Flutter on desktop this error will display
the error only this project but when I create new project and run on desktop will run successful.

[image]

1. I try move lib and dependencies New project not working

Comment: check from your device its enable or not . you need to enable the web settings

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.